# Replace Multiple Values

Tags: r

I would like to replace multiple values in a dataframe. Dataframe refers to `lookup` table (data.frame) and replace values accordingly (refer `old_val` and `new_val` columns in `lookup` df). Code below works fine. The only issue it has when it does not find match in the lookup table it returns NA. I want to retain the original value in the dataframe.

```
   library(dplyr)
   foo <- data.frame(snp1 = c("AA", "AG", "AA", "AA"), 
                      snp2 = c("AA", "AT", "AG", "AA"), 
                      snp3 = c(NA, "GG", "GG", "GC"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
    
    lookup <- data.frame(old_val = c("AA", "AC", "AG"), 
                         new_val = c("0101", "0102", "0103"))
    
    foo2 <- foo %>% dplyr::select("snp1","snp2")
    foo2[] <- lookup$new_val[match(unlist(foo2), lookup$old_val)]
    output <- cbind(foo2, foo[!colnames(foo) %in% colnames(foo2)]) %>% 
      select(colnames(foo))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a base R approach :

```
foo2 <- foo
foo2[] <- lookup$new_val[match(unlist(foo2), lookup$old_val)]
foo2[is.na(foo2)] <- foo[is.na(foo2)]
foo2

#  snp1 snp2 snp3
#1 0101 0101 <NA>
#2 0103   AT   GG
#3 0101 0103   GG
#4 0101 0101   GC
```

Answer (score 3):

We create a named vector from 'lookup' with `deframe`, loop `across` the columns of 'foo', use the named vector to match and replace the column values and then `coalesce` with the original column to return the original value if there is no match with the lookup vector.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
foo %>% 
     mutate(across(everything(), ~ coalesce(deframe(lookup)[.], .)))
```

-output

```
#   snp1 snp2 snp3
#1 0101 0101 <NA>
#2 0103   AT   GG
#3 0101 0103   GG
#4 0101 0101   GC
```